# How to move first child to the end?

Tags: jquery

i have some div items in div container and i want to animate them continously.

i know how to run my function in endless loop, but there is a problem with selecting first div, animate it and move it to the end after done animation.

my function looks like this:

```
function MoveItems() {
        $(".container:first").animate(
            {width: "0px"},
            1000,
            function (){ 
                $('.container').append($(this));
                $('.container').remove($(this));
            }
        );
};
```

what i'm doing wrong? ;/

**edit:**

You are right about remove, but the animation still is not working.

i think that selector is not working corectly.

my html is:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="image"><a href=""><img src="img/image001.jpg" /><span>IMAGE001</span></a></div>
<div class="image"><a href=""><img src="img/image002.jpg" /><span>IMAGE002</span></a></div>
<div class="image"><a href=""><img src="img/image003.jpg" /><span>IMAGE003</span></a></div>
  <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="img/image004.jpg" /><span>IMAGE004</span></a></div>
</div>
```

but after running function MoveItems once there is:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="img/image001.jpg"><span>IMAGE001</span></a></div>
    <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="img/image002.jpg"><span>IMAGE002</span></a></div>
    <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="img/image003.jpg"><span>IMAGE003</span></a></div>
    <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="img/image004.jpg"><span>IMAGE004</span></a></div>
</div>
```

so the functions is operating on .container not a first child of container. am i here more specific? :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/ you dont need to remove.

Comment: @repas , you might have posted as answer

Comment: oh its not an answer this was just a lil question, and this is a lil aswer :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$(".container:first")` selects the first .container it finds.

You want `$(".container>div:first")`

You can also "speed up" the final remove/append by operating on parent instead of doing another DOM search for .container:

```
var $me = $(this);
$me.parent().append($me);
```

Comment: Levi Morrison made a lesson, but this is the line that helps with my function. TY.

Answer (score 6):

`append` automatically removes the child from the parent and places it at the end. `remove` will remove the child again, without adding it back on.

just drop the line: `$('.container').remove($(this));`

Answer (score 2):

remove this line:

```
$('.container').remove($(this));
```

append() doesn't create a copy, it moves the selected objects from their current position to the end of the target.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more practical example: http://jsfiddle.net/8KyCD/1/

It creates a jQuery plugin so that you can animate the items on any element.  I didn't set it up to loop, as you said you already know how to do that ;)

**Edit:** here's another example that hides the element, then shows it, and repeats forever: http://jsfiddle.net/8KyCD/5/  *[(documented code)](http://jsfiddle.net/8KyCD/9)*

Comment: it is magic. it is working, but i dont really understand much from that. :)

and i have to stop animation when mouseover so i should use my loop.

good job man!

great tool this jsfiddle.

Comment: I'll beef up an example with some comments and add the mouseover stuff.  Give me a bit time an' it'll be don, mate.

Comment: I originally misread your comment.  I left functionality the same but http://jsfiddle.net/8KyCD/9/ has the comments for what I've done.  I'm glad I could introduce you to jsfiddle :)  Don't forget to accept one of the responses as your answer ;)

Comment: For posterities sake, a cleaned, updated, and documented version is also available: http://jsfiddle.net/8KyCD/12/