# Navigation of items in a list

Tags: jquery, html, css

- I have 15 items in a list
- I have 10 such lists
- Each list SHOULD OCCUPY at most 1 row on the page
- Overflow items should be navigated via "NEXT" or "PREV" button.
- For displaying items in each list, I "float:left".
- But then the overflow items wrap to next row.

For now, I am doing a hack for my ***laptop screen size:***

- I .hide() all items at window load for each list
- Then .show() first 4 items for each list
- I have configured next and prev buttons accordingly.

I am positive this is wrong. But it enabled me to see how the look and feel is of what I wanted to do.

Please suggest me the correct approach. All major websites handle this. This is very common problem. I am just ignorant for now.

Comment: We should not *overuse* our ability to down vote somebody. It is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem by another SO response:

[How to move first child to the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480049/how-to-move-first-child-to-the-end)

Thanks for all your help

Comment: To be complete, to do the reverse, use prepend on the last element of the collection

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is probably:

1. Don't use float:left, just use regular inline display.
2. For the container element, use overflow:hidden.
3. Wrap the container element in an outer container, also with overflow:hidden.
4. Now, when the user clicks next/prev, adjust/animate the margin of the inner container, so that it slides across to reveal the other elements.

Comment: How would I know that I have reach the last element? In the beginning I dont know how many items were displayed...so I can not maintain a counter

Comment: I want to maintain a circular sliding effect. How can I do that with this approach?

Comment: @gauravjain what do you mean circular sliding?

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 (next click) 2 3 4 5 1 (next click) 3 4 5 1 2 (next click) 4 5 1 2 3 ( and so on). Its like a loop

Comment: with the above you suggested, I keep moving left and once I reach end of list, it shows blank spaces...which I did not like...